# Variable number of nested for loops with fixed range

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

I'm looking for a method to have a variable number of nested for loops instead of the following code. For example if the variable **n** represents the number of nested for loops and **n = 3**, my code would be:

```
p = []
for i in range(26):
  for j in range(26):
    for k in range(26):
      p.append([i,j,k])
```

Instead, if **n = 2** my code would be:

```
p = []
for i in range(26):
  for j in range(26):
    p.append([i,j])
```

I understand this can be done using recursion but I'm a bit confused as to how I'd go about doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important for one to develop the skills to reason about these problems. In this case, Python includes `itertools.product` but what happens the next time you need to write a behaviour specific to your program? Will there be another magical built-in function? Maybe someone else will have published a 3rd party library to solve your problem?

Below, we design `product` as a simple recursive function that accepts 1 or more lists.

```
def product (first, *rest):
  if not rest:
    for x in first:
      yield (x,)
  else:
    for p in product (*rest):
      for x in first:
        yield (x, *p)

for p in product (range(2), range(2), range(2)):
  print ('x: %d, y: %d z: %d' % p)

# x: 0, y: 0 z: 0
# x: 1, y: 0 z: 0
# x: 0, y: 1 z: 0
# x: 1, y: 1 z: 0
# x: 0, y: 0 z: 1
# x: 1, y: 0 z: 1
# x: 0, y: 1 z: 1
# x: 1, y: 1 z: 1
```

Assuming you want a more conventional iteration ordering, you can accomplish do so by using an auxiliary `loop` helper

```
def product (first, *rest):
  def loop (acc, first, *rest):
    if not rest:
      for x in first:
        yield (*acc, x)
    else:
      for x in first:
        yield from loop ((*acc, x), *rest)
  return loop ((), first, *rest)

for p in product (range(2), range(2), range(2)):
  print ('x: %d, y: %d z: %d' % p)

# x: 0, y: 0 z: 0
# x: 0, y: 0 z: 1
# x: 0, y: 1 z: 0
# x: 0, y: 1 z: 1
# x: 1, y: 0 z: 0
# x: 1, y: 0 z: 1
# x: 1, y: 1 z: 0
# x: 1, y: 1 z: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
import itertools

n=3
fixed=26
p = list(itertools.product(range(fixed), repeat=n))
```

This solution uses the optimized functions of `itertools`, so it should be quite fast.

Mind that `itertools.product` returns an iterator, so one needs to transform it to get an array.

Comment: You can replace `[x for x in iterable]` with `list (iterable)`