# Python: Dynamic nested for loops each with different range

Tags: python, loops, dynamic, nested-loops

I want to create a code that can iterate over a dynamic number (N) of nested loops each with different range.
For example:

```
N=3 
ranges=[[-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3],
 [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  [-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3]]

for x in ranges[0]:
    for y in ranges[1]:
        for z in range[2]:
            variable=[x, y, z]
```

Im new to python. As I went over similar questions posted here I have the understanding that this can be done with recursion or itertools. However, none of the answers posted solve this problem for a different range at each level.
The closest posted question similar to mine was [Variable number of nested for loops with fixed range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49306528/variable-number-of-nested-for-loops-with-fixed-range) . However, the answer posted by user633183 is coded in python 3.X and I am coding in python 2.7 so I couldn't implement it as some of its code does not work on python 2.7. 
Can you please help me to code this problem. Thanks!

Comment: You will get more and better answers if you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.  Especially make sure that the input and expected test data are complete (not pseudo-data), and can be easily cut and and paste into an editor to allow testing proposed solutions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterating over a 2 dimensional python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16548668/iterating-over-a-2-dimensional-python-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is equivalent to `itertools.product`:

```
print(list(itertools.product(*ranges)))
```

Comment: Thanks. I used this code v=list(itertools.product(*ranges))
for i in range(len(v)):
    var=v[i]
    do Something with var

Answer (score 1):

So, if I am understanding your question correctly, you want the values being iterated over to be `[-3, -5, -3], [-2, -4, -2]...`.  This can be accomplished easily with zip function built into python:

```
for x in zip(*ranges):
    # Do something with x
```

x will take on a tuple of all the first values, then a tuple of all the second values, etc, stopping when the shortest list ends.  Using this `*` splat notation avoids even having to know about the number of lists being combined.